# attach only recent file in PowerShell email

Tags: powershell

Dears
i have the script which send email with attachment lof file , my issue that  the path includes many log files , i need to know how can i only attach latest log file only.

```
$PSEmailServer = "mail.mail.com"
    $SMTPPort = 587
    $SMTPUsername = "my.email@mail.com"
    $EncryptedPasswordFile = "my.email@mail.com.securestring"
    $SecureStringPassword = Get-Content -Path $EncryptedPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $EmailCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $SMTPUsername,$SecureStringPassword
    $MailTo = "abc@mail.com"
    $MailFrom = "my.email@mail.com"
    $MailSubject = "my subject"
    $MailBody = "kindly check the attached log"
    $att = "C:\email\log.txt"
    Send-MailMessage -From $MailFrom -To $MailTo -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody -Attachments 
$att -Port $SMTPPort -Credential $EmailCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the latest logfile from the path, you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\email' -Filter '*.txt' -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Next, I would suggest you use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for cmdlets like `Send-MailMessage` that take a lot of parameters.
This saves you from creating many variables and makes the code more readable/maintainable.

```
$att = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\email' -Filter '*.txt' -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
$mailParams = @{
    To          = "abc@mail.com"
    From        = "my.email@mail.com"
    Subject     = "my subject"
    Body        = "kindly check the attached log"
    Port        = 587
    Credential  = $EmailCredential  # get this from file or use the Get-Credential cmdlet
    Attachments = $att.FullName     # needs an (aray of) full path and filename
}
# now send the email
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```